# Reverse Regular expressions

Tags: popularity-contest, regular-expression

The idea here is to write a little segment that will spit out regular expression patterns when given a string that matches them.

As you might have guessed, this will be a popularity contest, and I'll accept whichever answer has the most upvotes by March 7th

pseudocode Example:

```
print(reverseRegex('dog')); 
//prints /[a-z]{3}/, /dog/, and a bunch other stuff
```

EDIT: The regular expressions spat out should not exceed 3 times the input string's length

Comment: I think the spec could do with tightening. There are countably infinitely many families of countably infinitely many regexes which match any given string.

Comment: What if the input string is longer than 30 chars?

Comment: @doorknob good point, will revise again

Comment: Now your sample output violates your own rules.

Comment: Will fix :P where would I be without you...

Comment: Maybe in the sandbox: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/954/proposed-questions-sandbox-mark-8

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby

```
def esc chr
  '\\[]'.index(chr) ? "\\#{chr}" : chr
end

def reverse_regex str
  ords = str.chars.to_a.uniq.map(&:ord).sort
  prev = ords.first
  ranges = ords.slice_before{|x|
    prev, prev2 = x, prev
    prev2 + 1 != x
  }.map{|x| x[0]..x[-1]}

  reversed = "[#{ranges.map{|c|esc(c.min.chr) + (c.min == c.max ? '' : (c.min + 1 == c.max ? '' : '-') + esc(c.max.chr))}*''}]{#{str.size}}"
  reversed.size > str.size * 3 ? /#{Regexp.escape str}/ : /#{reversed}/
end
```

Sample outputs:

```
reverse_regex 'dogs are delicious'
  => /[ ac-egilorsu]{18}/
reverse_regex 'a'
  => /a/
reverse_regex ''
  => //
reverse_regex 'This is a test: []{}.*potato'
  => /[ *.:T\[\]aehiopst{}]{28}/
```

Now with ranges!

These regexen match the entire string (if you added `^...$` it would still match, but I'm too lazy to do that and add the required length check). Also, I'm assuming the `/`s don't count for length. (If they did, it would be impossible for input of empty string.)

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3.2

If you wish for soemthing very short, as usual you can use `python`.

It is well known that you can do anything in `python` with few `import`s. In this case, this task is such simple that in `python 3.2` you don't even need an `include`.

```
def reverse_regex(string):
    return '/.*/'

print (reverse_regex('dog'))
print (reverse_regex('I can haz a cheezburger.'))
print (reverse_regex('123-ABC-abc'))
```

You will see all these expression are valid.

UPDATE:

This new code (although a bit more long) is able to show multiple regex for eacah word.

```
def reverse_regex(string):
    print ('/.*/')
    print ('/'+string+'/')

reverse_regex('dog')
reverse_regex('I can haz a cheezburger.')
reverse_regex('123-ABC-abc')
```

Comment: the idea is that it should spit out different expressions for each string, and more than one of them

Comment: thx, corrected.